# UIBarButtonItem position incorrect on < iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios10

On iOS 10 and below my bar buttons are positioned incorrectly within the nav bar. What could be causing this?

This is the function to set the button:

```
func setBarButton(image: UIImage?, position: BarButtonPosition, target: AnyObject, selector: Selector) -> Void {
  let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: target, action: selector)
  barButton.image = image

  if position == .left {
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.zbPrimary
  } else {
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.zbPrimary
  }
}
```

And where I am calling the function within `viewDidLoad`:

```
setBarButton(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "settings-icon"), position: .right, target: self, selector: #selector(openSettings))
```

This only happens for `UIBarButtonItem` where an image is being set, not those with just a title or custom view

[image]

Comment: Asked right question. As per your description and header looking weird.

Comment: Why do you use the `UIBarButtonItem`'s initializer with a title if you don't need a title? Try passing the image directly to the initializer without setting an empty title and check if anything changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question was misleading but after reading your question I realized it was the same problem I had on one of my projects.
I was setting the barButtonItem title through code and when I changed it from:

- **navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = ""**

To:

- **navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = nil**

The problem disappeared.
I almost lost a entire day to fix this.
I hope this solves the problem for you.

Comment: Not sure how the question title is misleading, how could I improve this? Nevertheless thank you for your answer, it appears to have fixed my problem

Comment: I said it was misleading because it said "> iOS 11" and it should be "< iOS 11".